# Git apply changes from a commit of a branch to an existing commit of other branch

Tags: git, branch, commit

I'm sorry if this has been discussed before, but since I haven't found any solution for this specific case so I thought I would ask here.

I had a branch (call it branch A) with 1 commit and created a new pull request from that branch. While waiting for review I created another branch (called B) with A as HEAD so I had its commit as well. I worked on branch B and during that time someone told me to update the commit in A. I used `git reset` and pushed the changes back to A. After that my PR went through. Now which command should I use to update the changes from branch A to B? I used `cherry-pick` but it created another commit in B and I dont want that, I want that commit to be updated "silently".

Comment: What do u mean by silently? Also you cannot 'update' a commit with `git reset`. You can only reset the changes. Did you mean to say you did a soft reset made the changes and committed again?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous Yeah I mean I reset the commit, make changes and commited again. I want the commit in branch B to be up-to-date with it of branch A without having to make another commit.

Comment: I figured as much, please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment notwithstanding, I understand you changed the commit you based your branch B on. To bring that commit on B while removing the original commit at HEAD follow these steps:

1. `git checkout <branch B>` (Move to branch B)
2. `git reset --hard HEAD~2` (Remove the first two commits in the branch)
3. `git cherry-pick <SHA-hash of the new commit in branch A>` (Add the new commit in the branch)

Comment: Will this make another commit in branch B? For example its current commits are: Commit1 - Commit2- Commit3 (Commit2 is what B based on and it has been changed, Commit3 is the new commit of branch B), will this create `Commit4` to indiacate that changes have been updated?

Comment: No, in this case, the second step will make it `Commit-1` and the third step will make it, `Commit-1 - Commit 3`, assuming Commit-3 is the edited commit you want